# Deleting rows by using a for loop + if statements

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I've the following dataframe:

```
caratteri <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
numeri <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
dataFrameMio <- data.frame(caratteri, numeri)
```

How can I delete the rows in which the value of the *numeri* column is 2 by using a for loop and if statements?

I need to do this because, in the case of a big dataframe, I cannot specify manually which rows to delete. I'm a newbie in R, maybe it's possible to do that also without a loop.

Comment: `dataFrameDiGenna=subset(dataFrameMio,numeri!=2)`?

Comment: You can use `result <- subset(dataFrameMio, numeri != 2)` without specifying which rows to delete. Do you *have* to use a loop ?

Comment: What happened to your same question, deleted? Please use "edit" instead of reposting.

Comment: You can use `dplyr::filter`, which avoir using a loop `library(dplyr)
dataFrameMio %>%
  filter(numeri != 2)`

Comment: @zx8754 it's a different question, here I'm asking a solution, not why my solution doesn't work

Comment: It reads as though the same to me, please undelete your post and link it here.

Comment: `df[which(df$numeri != 2),]` is also a possibility.

Comment: @Chris great suggestion

Comment: @Chris be careful with naming dataframes `df` as `df` is also a function in R. R will deal completely sensible with it but once you do something wrong that can be a reason for incomprehensible error messages. Also `which` is an unnecessary step we do not need here. It will be very fast so it is not a problem, still it is not needed.

Comment: @Bernhard thanks, `df` now noted, and of course `df1[df1$numeri !=2, ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you really should not do this via a `for` loop but you can:

```
caratteri <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
numeri <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
dataFrameMio <- data.frame(caratteri, numeri)

result <- list()
for(line in 1:nrow(dataFrameMio))
  if(dataFrameMio$numeri[line] != 2) 
    result <- rbind(result, dataFrameMio[line,])

print(result)
```

This ist difficult to read and to find errors in and it will perform poorly with larger datasets. Just use `subset`!
Or square brackets as in

```
dataFrameMio[dataFrameMio$numeri != 2,]
```